# South Korea travel visa - When do I leave?

Tags: visas, international-travel, us-citizens, south-korea

If you are a US citizen and travel to South Korea under the 90 day visa-free policy, when do you have to leave? Is it the 90th day or the 89th day?

Comment: Can you mention the date the visa is valid till on your passport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They make it easy for you: your passport is stamped with the date of entry and the last day by which you have to leave:

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words and all that. ☺