# Legality of "volunteering" for room & board (and language class) in South Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea, volunteering

[This hostel](https://www.helpgoabroad.com/language-schools/learn-korean-language-volunteering-in-korea-busan-8318/) offers bed, food, and language class in return for work.  In USA and other countries, this requires a working visa.  In Spain it is legal.¹  How is it in South Korea?

The website is an aggregator.  The hostel's own website is merely a blog full of testimonials with a pointer to a Korean language Facebook page for more info.

¹Or seems to be, because the police don't do anything to stop it.

Comment: The fact that the police do not frequently stop it is not evidence of legality.

Comment: That's why the footnote.  It happens all along the Camino, the police are well aware, and they don't interfere.  Opposite in USA.  The WWOOF website actually advises you to lie at the border, to tell them you are a tourist, and don't mention volunteering.

Comment: The police are aware? Try to file a complaint with the immigration department and see if they really don't care...

Comment: Actually, there have been complaints about the place I worked, and they’ve been required to change policies on a few things, but not on giving volunteers room and board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completely illegal. All you need is one phone call to immigration and that place will be raided. This is not volunteering, but real work -- 2 pm to 10 pm?!? Really?!? -- and while payment is in kind rather than in cash, it is still payment. And quite a cheap payment at that.

A tourist visa in Korea does not allow you any kind of work -- paid and unpaid. This is clearly in violation of the law.

Comment: Though I think your answer is correct, it'd be great if you had a reference or some source for it.

Comment: Well, the "work" actually sounds fun to me, but the legality is my concern.  I've done something similar in Spain.  Second the request for a citation.

Comment: Besides having spent a decade and a half there, employing Koreans and foreigners, and having had myself every kind of visa, from tourist to D-8 (foreign investor), and thus having a little experience with the Immigration act (and the Labor Laws), it's all there https://elaw.klri.re.kr/eng_service/lawView.do?hseq=33079&lang=ENG mostly Article 18.

Comment: Took ages for that page to load, but it is quite plain.  Maybe they arrange the proper visa, but if not, it's even illegal to have that website.

Comment: Nowhere do these guys mention a visa. That's why they say volunteer. But that's BS. That's illegal employment. I'm actually considering reporting them next month, when I'm in Seoul.

Comment: I didn’t say they mention it, I said maybe.  I doubt it, but it’s possible.  The website isn’t theirs, so it has no incentive to protect them or to give the right story.  I suspect the hostel people just don’t know what they’re doing.  But if they do, they’ve probably figured out how to avoid prosecution.